# How to do a LEFT JOIN in MS Access without duplicates?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, left-join

I have 2 tables with duplicated values in one of the columns. I'd like to do a left join without taking rows, where mentioned column values duplicates.
For example,
i have table X:

```
id  Value
A   2
B   4
C   5
```

and table Y:

```
id   Value
A  2
A  8
B  2
```

I'm doing a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT*
FROM X LEFT JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.id;
```

Would like to have something like:

```
id   Value
A   2   A   2
B   4   B   2
C   5
```

so that duplicated id (A   8) from table Y is not considered.

Comment: Does access support the keyword "distinct"?

Comment: yes, i think it considers just where the full row is duplicated, in my case just 1 column value is duplicated

Comment: unfortunately no. is not there a way for access?

Comment: are you sure your ID column is for A, B, C? Didn't you reverse the columns?

Comment: how is `A 8` a duplicate? Don't you mean `A 2`?

Comment: @Marc B i meant that in row A 8 id is duplicated. i'd like to cut all the rows where id is duplicated, so from Y table to take A id just once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT X.id, X.value, MIN(Y.value)
FROM X
LEFT JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.id
GROUP BY X.id, X.value
```

Note that it is not necessary to bring `Y.id` into the mix, because it is either `null` or equal to `X.id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it valid also if the value is a Text, not integer?

Comment: @Ale Yes, `MIN` and `MAX` aggregate functions remain valid for strings as well, but they mean lexicographically first / last string. The decision of what item to take when there's more than one matching row is central to formulating your query. I used `MIN` because your sample result picked `2` from the list of `2` and `8`.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for GROUP BY to aggregate the Y table records, effectively collapsing them down to one row per id. I have chosen MIN but you could use SUM if they are integers like your example data.

```
SELECT 
    x.id , x.Value, y.id, min(y.value)
FROM 
    X LEFT JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.id 
GROUP BY 
    x.id, x.value, y.id;
```

I have given exactly what you asked for. But in my opinion the y.Id is unnecessary in the select and group by list.

Comment: but if the id is not an integer, but a text? how to manage it? (in my example, there were just fake tables)

Comment: MIN will work for text, it will select the first item alphabetically

Comment: +1 . . . This answer was not only first but it is also more accurate, including all four columns mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you're asking for in particular, but if you don't need them joined you could use a union.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ID, VALUE FROM tableX 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ID, VALUE FROM TAbleY)
GROUP BY ID, Value
```

You would end up getting

```
id   Value
A    2
A    4
A    8
B    2
B    4
C    5
```

Comment: no, unfortunately, i need a join, so that i can add to the left table some missing data from the right table. and like A 8 row i don't need at all

Comment: @Ale Okay. I'll still leave the answer here for future SO browsers in case they are looking for a solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I think you can do this in Access with correlated subqueries:

```
select x.*,
       (select top 1 y.id
        from y
        where y.id = x.id
       ),
       (select top 1 y.value
        from y
        where y.id = x.id
       ),
from x;
```

This doesn't guarantee that the values come from the same row, but that's not a big deal in this case, because the `y.id` is either present (and the same as `x.id`) or it is `NULL`.  The `y.value` comes from an arbitrary matching row.

Comment: It's solved by using `MIN` function. But thanks in anyway! :)